# getting the error in mongose Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ _id: 'allchatroom' }\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"user\""

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, postman

```js
module.exports.allchatrooms = async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const details = await Chatroom.find({});
    return res.status(200).send({
      status: 200,
      message: "all the chatroom",
      data:details,
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      status: 00,
      err: error,
    });
  }
};
```

```css
error in postman

{
    "status": 400,
    "success": false,
    "err": {
        "stringValue": "\"{ _id: 'allchatroom' }\"",
        "valueType": "Object",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": {
            "_id": "allchatroom"
        },
        "path": "_id",
        "reason": {},
        "name": "CastError",
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ _id: 'allchatroom' }\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"user\""
    }
}
```

```html
model file 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Chatroom =  new mongoose.Schema({
    chatroom_name:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    }

 })
 
module.exports =  mongoose.model('chat',Chatroom);
```

i am try to make the chatroom application for the practice because i am new in this field so try to make this project how can handle the real time data but when i hit the api to get all the chatrooms list then i got this error

Comment: That looks like a router issue, is your `:id` router before or after your `allchatroom` route?

Comment: no its just http://localhost:3000/users/allchatroom

Comment: How is that URL processed to get to one of the functions in the question?  And which of the routes refers to req.param.id?

Comment: router.get('/users/allchatroom',controller.allchatrroms); i want get all the chatroom from the DB so user can join any one

Comment: Is that the only route?

Comment: There is other crud operation route of user